# Display the 2 most recent post on home page

Tags: php, wordpress

So I would like to display the 2 most recent post on the home page but on the category show the latest 15 or 20 post. I know wordpress has the option to set how many post to show but I dont know what code I need to edit or add to only show 2 on the homepage. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `Dashboard => Settings => Reading => Blog pages show at most`

Comment: I know how to set that but I dont know how to set it to show 2 on the home page and a different number on another page

Comment: use posts_per_page and order DESC

Answer (score 0):

Use [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook. This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run ( so there is no performance cost ). It is possible to override the posts_per_page setting ( `Blog pages show at most` ) on a case-by-case basis. The following example demonstrates how to override the posts_per_page setting on home page.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {

    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
    }

});
```

Comment: Default [order](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) is `DESC`, default orderby is `date`.